# Activity Declaration

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I am working on App lock Application in Android, the error I am facing is 
`Utils.java`

```
public class Util {
    public static void Job(Context con){
        ComponentName service=new ComponentName(con,AppsService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder build=new JobInfo.Builder(0,service);
        build.setMinimumLatency(1*1000);
        build.setOverrideDeadline(3*1000);
        build.setRequiresCharging(false);
        JobScheduler schedule=con.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        schedule.schedule(build.build());
    }
}
```

LockActivity.java

```
public class LockActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock);
    final TextInputEditText pass=(TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    Button submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String password=pass.getText().toString();
            DataBase data=DataBase.getInstance(LockActivity.this);
            data.insertPass(password);
            pass.setText("");
            Intent i=new Intent(LockActivity.this,Util.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.darkweb.android.applock">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LockActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AppsDisplay" />
    <activity android:name=".UnlockActivity"></activity>

    <receiver android:name="MyStartServiceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**Error** :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.darkweb.android.applock/com.darkweb.android.applock.Util}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

 at com.darkweb.android.applock.LockActivity$1.onClick(LockActivity.java:33)
```

## Line 33 includes = Intent method

Comment: There error clears tell you, You may have not declared your `Activity` in Manifest?

Comment: Util is not an activity class then why you launch this as activity class in intent?

Comment: You don't need `Intent i=new Intent(LockActivity.this,Util.class);
            startActivity(i);` to start a job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
Intent i=new Intent(LockActivity.this,Util.class);
startActivity(i);
```

You are trying to run `Util.class` as an Activity using the `Intent` class but That's not correct as Intent is used to run Activities not accessing regular classes, `Util.class` is just a class that you should access directly using an instance of the class or even using the class itself as the method inside is static:

```
Util.Job(context);
```

And you don't have to add it in the **manifest.xml** as it is a regular class not an Activity.

---

How to access it:

```
public class LockActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock);
    final TextInputEditText pass=(TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    Button submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Util.Job(LockActivity.this);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I got it . Thanks

Comment: @AjayMishra great, so please accept my answer if it is solves your problem :)

Comment: one issue , what I have to put here inside Job()
 Intent intent = new Intent(LockActivity.this, Util.Job());  which context

Comment: @AjayMishra it is a regular method you don't need to call it using the intent, just see my updated answer

Comment: ok, done with this , after launching getting error

Scheduled service ComponentInfo{com.darkweb.android.applock/com.darkweb.android.applock.AppsService} does not require android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission

thought I have declared it 
 <service
            android:name=".AppsService"

            android:exported="true"/>

Comment: @AjayMishra Please have a look at my answer && the tutorial as well. It will solve all your queries. the app service class does not  require .BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission instead the Util class requires that permission which needs to extend JobService.

Answer (score 0):

> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Util is a class **not an activity**

You can't access a regular class with an intent

Comment: problem in declaring the activity in manifest , as it doesn't extends Activity Class.
I got this code from Github

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the activity/service in your manifest

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
```

Please have a look at this [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129) for more information.

Make a service that extends job service.

```
public class SomeJobService extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = SomeJobService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside scheduleJob of onStartJob");
        //do some work()
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        return false;
    }

    public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside scheduleJob of SomeJobService");

        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(1000,
                    new ComponentName(context, AppsService.class))
                    .setMinimumLatency(1*1000);
                    .setOverrideDeadline(3*1000);
                    .setRequiresCharging(false);
                    .build());
        }
```

In your lockActivity Call this function

```
SomeJobService.scheduleJob(this);
```

And also add this to your manifest.

```
<service
android:name=".service.SomeJobService"
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

Comment: getting the same error after adding the permission!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the question ?? mainly the flow of the code.You cannot execute the job scheduler wherever you like.Look in the tutorial.

Comment: I am sending data from one LockActivity to class Util , Util is a class. Error is u can see Activity Util not declared , but it is a class not Activity